# How to deploy an Electron app as a executable or installable in Windows

Tags: reactjs, electron

Its a react application using web pack react code minimized to bundle.js. Have problem in coverting into exe. its working in electron window when running electron ./main.js

```
Folder structure is :
poc/
├── package.json
├── bundle.js
├── main.js
└── index.html
```

Comment: I have solved the issue have used electron-packager and windows-installer.

https://github.com/electron/windows-installer

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue have used electron-packager and windows-installer.

[electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager)
[windows-installer](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer)

Comment: Can you please describe what you've done to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the README, click [this](https://github.com/Urucas/electron-packager-interactive/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would recommened to use [Electron Builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder). Ist supports Windows,Mac and Linux builds. It also support builds for Electron Auto-Updater.